# C: scanf with ==

Tags: c, scanf

I saw this piece of code. I am quite new in C, so pardon me.

The `while` loop below will keep looping `if i < SIZE && scanf("%f",&Arr[i]) == 1`.

I get the `i < SIZE` part but what does `scanf("%f",&Arr[i]) == 1` mean?
I know it is taking in the value from `scanf()` and assigning it to an array `Arr`. But what does the `== 1` means?

Thanks :)

```
int readValue(float Arr[]) {
    int i = 0 ;
    while (i < SIZE && scanf("%f",&Arr[i]) == 1) 
        i++ ;  
    return i ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably would be clearer if there were some more parentheses in here to help keep in mind [Operator Precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm):

```
while (i < SIZE && scanf("%f",&Arr[i]) == 1)
```

is the same as

```
while ((i < SIZE) && (scanf("%f", &Arr[i]) == 1))
```

So if `i` happens to be `>= SIZE` the `==` is irrelevant as it won't be executed at all. If `i` is less than `SIZE` then [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) will be called and will return the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. So in your case, if this was 1 (if we got a float and put it in `Arr[i]`) then the conditions are met.

So you'll loop until `i` gets bigger than or equal to `SIZE` or if an invalid entry is entered into `scanf()`

For example if you enter the letter "h", your loop will break because that can't go into a float specificer, so `scanf()` will return 0.

Answer (score 2):

[`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of assignments made, in this `1` is expected to made so if `scanf()` returns `1` then `&Arr[i]` has been successfully assigned a value. From the linked reference page the return value is described as:

> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned, or EOF if read failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned

Comment: Hi there,
In this case, to end the while loop.
I do a ctrl + D which is something like a EOF?

Comment: @LawrenceWong, I _think_ the meaning of `ctrl + D` differs between platforms. In this case, you could just enter an invalid `float` value that would terminate the while (`"done"` for example).

Answer (score 1):

The return value of [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) is the number of items of the argument list successfully filled.

Since there is one argument, a return value of `1` means that the call was successful. If the input could not be interpreted as a floating point number you would get a return value of `0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` returns the number of elements successfully read:

From man page:

> ...functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in
>   the event of an early matching failure.

So if input was successful for a single float value, `scanf()` will return `1` and condition will be true in the while loop for second part of the condition.